# Explain JavaScript code process in plain English

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning on Udacity and they have a quiz which I couldn't pass myself. I decided to look at the provided solution but I need to understand the process of the code (I understand some of it). Here it is:

```js
// creates a line of * for a given length
function makeLine(length) {
    var line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
        line += "* ";
    }
    return line + "\n";
}

// your code goes here.  Make sure you call makeLine() in your own code.
function buildTriangle(length) {
    // Let's build a huge string equivalent to the triangle
    var triangle = "";

    //Let's start from the topmost line
    var lineNumber = 1;

    for(lineNumber=1; lineNumber<=length; lineNumber++){
        // We will not print one line at a time.
        // Rather, we will make a huge string that will comprise the whole triangle
        triangle = triangle + makeLine(lineNumber);
    }
    return triangle;
}

// test your code by uncommenting the following line
// Note that the function buildTriangle() must return a string 
// because the console.log() accepts a string argument
console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```

I understand that makeLine() will create line of asterisks based on the value of length that passed to it when it gets called inside buildTriangle()

But I don't understand how this line works:

```
triangle = triangle + makeLine(lineNumber);
```

Is it not working like the line in makeLine () which is

```
line += "* ";
```

What's the difference between using `+=` and `triangle = triangle + makeLine(lineNumber)`? If they work same then the output should be wrong.

Also please correct me if I'm wrong in my understanding to the variable length in makeLine(length) and buildTriangle (length). Are they different variables because of different scope? Can I change the name of the variable in buildTriangle function to be something like buildTriangle (passedValueToMakeLineFunc)?

Finally it would be highly appreciated if someone imitate the JavaScript engine and described how it will handle that code step by step in plain English.

Comment: Quick answer: Try editing the code to be `triangle += makeLine(lineNumber);`. You should notice the output is the same as when you use `triangle = triangle + makeLine(lineNumber);`!

Comment: _"Are they different variables because of different scope?"_ - yep, that's correct, you're free to change the variable name to any other valid variable name

Comment: Alright JohnKugelman, got it. Tq :)
@DemiPixel yes, worked same. but I'm still confused. The first loop round in buildTriangle function calls makeLine function which will return first asterisk string "* " with new line "\n ", so in the second loop round the passed value to makeLine() increased by 1 so it will return 2 asterisks "** " but since we used += the 2 asterisks will be added to the first "* " from the first loop round and will return 3 asterisks instead of 2  for the second line. I think I need more explanation for how += works  or how each loop round deals with the previous round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what's the difference between using += and triangle = triangle + makeLine(lineNumber)

These are equivalent:

```js
triangle = triangle + makeLine(lineNumber);
```

```js
triangle += makeLine(lineNumber);
```

---

> …the variable length in makeLine(length) and buildTriangle (length) ... are they different variables…

Correct.

1. The variables are entirely independent and
2. you can call them whatever you want.

---

> step by step in plain English

Apologies if this is too verbose or not what you had in mind:

- declare functions `makeLine` and `buildTriangle` (define but do not execute)
- invoke `buildTriangle` with a single argument (`10`) to resolve value to be passed to `console.log`

Execution of buildTriangle:

```js
function buildTriangle(length) {
    // Let's build a huge string equivalent to the triangle
    var triangle = "";

    //Let's start from the topmost line
    var lineNumber = 1;

    for(lineNumber=1; lineNumber<=length; lineNumber++){
        // We will not print one line at a time.
        // Rather, we will make a huge string that will comprise the whole triangle
        triangle = triangle + makeLine(lineNumber);
    }
    return triangle;
}
```

- begin execution of `buildTriangle` with `length = 10`
- declare a variable called `triangle` with an initial empty string value
- declare a variable called `lineNumber` with an initial value of `1`.
- initialize `for` loop: set variable `lineNumber` to `1` (again)
- evaluate `for` loop condition. is `lineNumber` less than or equal to `length` (10)?
- lineNumber is 1, which is less than 10, so loop condition is true. execute loop body.
- evaluate `makeLine(1)` (lineNumber is 1)

Execution of makeLine:

```js
function makeLine(length) {
    var line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
        line += "* ";
    }
    return line + "\n";
}
```

- begin execution of `makeLine` with `length = 1`
- declare variable called `line` and initialize to empty string
- begin `for` loop: declare and initialize variable `j` with initial value `1`
- evaluate `for` loop condition. is `j` less than or equal to `length` (1)?
- j is 1, which is equal to 1, so loop condition is true. execute loop body.
- append `"* "` to `line`. (`line` is now `"* "`)
- increment `j`. `j` is now `2`.
- evaluate `for` loop condition. is `j` less than or equal to `length` (1)?
- `j` is `2`. condition is false. exit loop.
- return `line` value with a newline appended: (`"* \n"`)

(Resume `buildTriangle` execution)

- set `triangle` to its current value (empty string) plus resolved `makeLine` value: `triangle` is now `"* \n"`
- end of loop body. run post-loop expression (lineNumber++)
- set `lineNumber` to 2
- evaluate `for` loop condition. is `lineNumber` less than or equal to `length` (10)?
- `lineNumber` is `2`, which is less than `10`, so loop condition is true. execute loop body.
- evaluate `makeLine(2)` (lineNumber is 2)

Execution of makeLine:

- begin execution of `makeLine` with `length = 2`
- declare variable called `line` and initialize to empty string
- begin `for` loop: declare and initialize variable `j` with initial value `1`
- evaluate `for` loop condition. is `j` less than or equal to `length` (2)?
- j is 1, which is less than 2, so loop condition is true. execute loop body.
- append `"* "` to `line`. (`line` is now `"* "`)
- increment `j`. `j` is now `2`.
- evaluate `for` loop condition. is `j` less than or equal to `length` (2)?
- j is 2, which is equal to 2, so loop condition is true. execute loop body.
- append `"* "` to `line`. (`line` is now `"* * "`)
- increment `j`. `j` is now `3`.
- evaluate `for` loop condition. is `j` less than or equal to `length` (2)?
- `j` is `3`. condition is false. exit loop.
- return `line` value with a newline appended: (`"* * \n"`)

(Resume `buildTriangle` execution)

- set `triangle` to its current value `"* \n"` plus resolved `makeLine` value: `triangle` is now `"* \n* * \n"`
- end of loop body. run post-loop expression (lineNumber++)
- set `lineNumber` to 3
- evaluate `for` loop condition. is `lineNumber` less than or equal to `length` (10)?
- `lineNumber` is `3`, which is less than `10`, so loop condition is true. execute loop body.
- evaluate `makeLine(3)` (lineNumber is 3)

Repeat steps above until lineNumber reaches 11 and loop exits.

- return value of `triangle` to caller and exit `buildTriangle`. At this point the value of `triangle` is:

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```

- invoke `console.log` with the value returned by `buildTriangle`.
- exit

---

Your example included here for reference:

```js
// creates a line of * for a given length
function makeLine(length) {
    var line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
        line += "* ";
    }
    return line + "\n";
}

// your code goes here.  Make sure you call makeLine() in your own code.
function buildTriangle(length) {
    // Let's build a huge string equivalent to the triangle
    var triangle = "";

    //Let's start from the topmost line
    var lineNumber = 1;

    for(lineNumber=1; lineNumber<=length; lineNumber++){
        // We will not print one line at a time.
        // Rather, we will make a huge string that will comprise the whole triangle
        triangle = triangle + makeLine(lineNumber);
    }
    return triangle;
}

// test your code by uncommenting the following line
// Note that the function buildTriangle() must return a string 
// because the console.log() accepts a string argument
console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```

Comment: Just came across this question while exploring randomly.
I haven't read the whole question and the answer but I still, appreciate @ray-hatfield for taking time to post an answer. 

Answer (score 2):

### Addition assignment operator (+=)

`someVar += "someString"` is the same as `someVar = someVar + "someString"`

Go ahead and replace your example with `triangle += makeLine(lineNumber)` and you'll see you get the same triangle.

### The 2 `length`s

In this case, they are both parameters to the functions `makeLine` and `buildTriangle`.

- Function parameters are scoped to the function block, meaning they are only available inside the function, not accessible outside.
- Name them as you like, this has no effect outside of the function block.
- Note that if a length parameter did in fact exist outside of the function declarations, the length parameter would over/hide the external variable from use inside the function.

```js
var length = 4;
console.log("outer", length); // 4
function someFunction(length) {
  console.log("inner", length); // 5
}
someFunction(5);
console.log("outer", length); // 4
```

### Code in english

*I'm going to assume this is a little too detailed in some places and maybe not enough in others. Enjoy the story!*

1. The `makeLine` function is declared (but not run yet)
2. The `buildTriangle` function is declared (but not run yet)
3. We hit a console.log() with a param of a function call (buildTriangle(10)). We'll execute that function, and the result of it will be passed to the log function call.
4. We've stepped into the `buildTriangle` function with a param length of value 10.
5. We make a `triangle` variable we'll build out the entire triangle into, new lines and all, initialized to an empty string.
6. We declare a lineNumber variable set to 1.

   - This one is just to mess with you
   - It did not need to be done before the for loop, would have been just the same to `for (var lineNumber=1; lineNumber<=length; lineNumber++){ ... }` and not declare it before hand.
   - It does not matter what it was or wasn't initialized to as the for loop sets it to 1 as it starts.
7. We hit a for loop, `for(lineNumber=1; lineNumber<=length; lineNumber++)`

   - We set `lineNumber` to 1
   - We will continue to run another iteration of this loop until `lineNumber` is <= length (10) (So up until and including 10)
   - We will, upon the completion of each iteration, before checking the continuation condition, increment the `lineNumber` by 1 (`lineNumber++`).
8. For each iteration of the loop (lineNumber values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) we execute `triangle = triangle + makeLine(lineNumber);` Which just takes the current `triangle` string, appends the result of `makeLine(lineNumber)` to it, and assigns that value to `triangle`.
9. We've stepped into the `makeLine` function with a param length of value 1.

   - Note at this point, the only variable available to our scope is the `length` param. (Besides the 2 functions I suppose)
10. We initialize a new variable `line` to an empty string.

    - **Note, this will be a brand new / separate *line* variable for every execution of this function** Sounds like this is where you maybe hung up?
    - Since the `line` variable is declared inside the function, it is scoped there, and is not accessible outside or across function executions.
    - This would be different if it were declared outside of the function and not reset at the begining. Then every execution would continue to just add on.
11. We encounter another for loop, this time with the iterator variable declared inside (j) `for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) { ... }`

    - We declare and initialize `j` to 1
    - We will continue to run another iteration of this loop until `j` is <= length (1) (So just 1 on this makeLine execution, subsequent times, 1-2, 1-3, ..., 1-10)
    - We will, upon the completion of each iteration, before checking the continuation condition, increment the `j` by 1 (`j++`).
12. For each iteration of the loop we execute `line += "* ";` which just takes the current `line` string, appends a "* " and assigns that value to `line`.
13. After this loop we encounter a return statement that is the result of combining our build out line with a newline character ("\n").
14. Assuming we've made it through all of our `buildTriangle` for loop iterations, we encounter our return statement and return the build out `triangle`.
15. We've now supplied the return value to be supplied as the parameter to console.log.
16. done.